# Using an ejs partial template breaks JSON.stringify

Tags: json, templates, sails.js, ejs, server-side-rendering

I'm using an ejs template to do server-side rendering within a sails app. In the template, I'm sending along a `var` inside a script tag to use on the client side, like this:

```
<script>
    var galleryObj = <%- JSON.stringify(gallery) %>;
</script>
```

This works fine.

However, when I add a `partial` higher up in the template, JSON.stringify throws a "circular object" error. So, the following Throws the error in the template file:

```
<div id="components">
    <% for (var idx = 0; idx < gallery.components.length; idx++) { %>
        <%- partial('partials/component', gallery.components[idx]) %>
    <% } %>
</div>

<script>
    var galleryObj = <%- JSON.stringify(gallery) %>;
</script>
```

However, it works with this modification:

```
<div id="components">
    <% var galleryJSON = JSON.stringify(gallery); %>
    <% for (var idx = 0; idx < gallery.components.length; idx++) { %>
        <%- partial('partials/component', gallery.components[idx]) %>
    <% } %>
</div>

<script>
    var galleryObj = <%- galleryJSON %>;
</script>
```

Clearly, using the partial is modifying the gallery object as used by the template, but I'm not sure how.

Some notes to help debug:

- the `partial` command within the template may be specific to using ejs from a sails app. I think "plain" ejs uses `include` to similar effect.
- each `gallery.components[idx]` have some property keys that match property keys for the whole `gallery` object, for example `createdAt`, etc.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?